# Kinesis Function Key Bindings

Tags: keyboard

I've a Kinesis Advantage Pro Keyboard and am using OS X Lion. I want to bind the function keys to what they are on the MacBook Pro - i.e. controls for brightness, mission control, etc.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Check this question on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/403493/kinesis-advantage-os-x-media-keys

Have you noticed sluggishness/hanging using the Advantage in Lion?  I've had issues with the shift key sticking (not physically, but it's like CAPS LOCK is on until I hit shift again), and delete key taking multiple presses to work, and other weirdness.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No, I've had a pretty smooth experience with Advantage and Snow Leopard/Lion/Mountain Lion so far. No hanging or sluggishness that I can recall. Have you tried your advantage on other computers & OSes?

Comment: I have a kinesis advantage usb, and randomly some modifier (shift, option, cmd, ctrl) will lock. Pressing the keys again will unlock. Annoying but infrequent, so bearable.

Answer (score 0):

I have added this to [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) in KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::COMMAND_L, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L | ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L | ModifierFlag::OPTION_L</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_1, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_BRIGHTNESS_DOWN</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_2, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_BRIGHTNESS_UP</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_6, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_MUSIC_PREV</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_7, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_MUSIC_PLAY</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_8, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_MUSIC_NEXT</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_9, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_VOLUME_DOWN, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_0, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_VOLUME_UP, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
```

The first line remaps the right command to control + option + command. I mainly use it as a modifier key for opening applications, but it serves as a substitute for fn in this case. I didn't use the F-keys, because key repeat is disabled for them, and they are harder to press without looking.

See the source for other [key code constants](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data).